# How to track my weight training?

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training

I've started weight training and I'm in my 4th week now. I'm seeing big improvements. Now I want to start tracking my workouts & diet. Is there a software or a website which allows me to do that?

Comment: http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/209/3778 for a list of applications. Also, if you want to craft your own, Google Forms combined with Excel et al are quite useful.

Comment: [thesquatrack.com](http://thesquatrack.com/) which is still in beta seems to be promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a variety of apps.

[Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com) is good for tracking workouts. It's gameified (you get points and levels for your workouts, and there are achievements) which can be fun and motivating.

[MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal) is good for tracking your diet. It has a large database of nutritional info of food, so the hardest part is recording an accurate portion size.

If you do a lot of running/cycling/rowing, then Runkeeper may also be useful. It plugs in to Fitocracy and MyFitnessPal nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I made [Evertrainer.com](https://www.evertrainer.com) as a lightweight program builder/tracker. Might be a good solution for your workout tracking.

Here's quick gif of it, to give you a sense of it:

[image: Editing a program on Evertrainer]